# AWS RDS - Postgres connection - Can't open instance locally

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, dbeaver

I've created an AWS RDS Postgres as a Free Tier for some development tests. Now, I'm trying to get a local connection using dbeaver, so I can interact with the databases locally. When I create the RDS connection I set up the access as **Public** and I already edit the Security group inbound rules as the following image:
[image]

However, when I try to make the connection with dbeaver, I got the following error message:

```
Connection attempt timed out.
```

I also try to increase the timeout number but without success.

What I can do more?

Thanks

Comment: That type of timeout is almost always a firewall issue.  Maybe you are trying to connect over ipv6 not ipv4?

Comment: Did you try to connect from a company network?

Comment: Was the database launched in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway)? Do you have any other resources in the same subnet that you can try connecting to, such as an Amazon EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some basic methods that you can try.

1. Use **netcat** to see if you can reach over your DB public over 5432 port.

```
nc -vz <YOUR_DB_PUBLIC> 5432
```

2. If you receive **connection time-out**, check your **RDS subnet groups** configuration to see if it includes **Public** subnets or mixed between **Public** and **Private**.
3. Again, check which **Subnet ID** that your DB instance is created under, go to VPC service, check the **Route Table** that is associated to that **Subnet ID**.
4. If the **Route Table** does not have a route to your Internet Gateway as below, you absolutely cannot access. Try adding the following route:

```
0.0.0.0/0  igw-123xyz
```